# Why graphicx package cause error in overleaf

Tags: compiler-errors, package, latex, document, overleaf

I'm having trouble using the graphicx package in my LaTeX document. Whenever I try to include an image, I get an error message that says 'File ended while scanning definition of @tempc.'. I've already added the graphicx package to my preamble, so I'm not sure what the issue could be.

```
    `\documentclass[a4paper,twocolumn]{article}
    \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
    \usepackage{graphicx}
    \usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
    \usepackage[numbers]{natbib}
    \usepackage{newcent}
    \usepackage{authblk}
    \usepackage{float,csquotes,booktabs}
    \usepackage[flushleft]{threeparttable}
    \usepackage{multicol}
    \usepackage{textcomp}
    \usepackage{gensymb}
    \usepackage[title]{appendix}
    %\usepackage{titlesec}
    \usepackage{xspace}
    \usepackage{longtable}
    \usepackage{soul}
    \usepackage{xltabular}
    \usepackage{lipsum}
    \usepackage{pifont}
    \newcommand{\cmark}{\ding{51}}%
    \newcommand{\xmark}{\ding{55}}%
    \usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry}
    \setlength{\columnsep}{2em}
    \usepackage{hyperref}
    \usepackage{cleveref}

   \usepackage{enumitem}`
```

Comment: Please make a compilable [mre]. After adding the necessary things to make your code fragment compilable, it seems to work fine. Please also check if other images work and show your .log file.